# How can I determine the latest Magento version supported for each package?

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2

I am working on a Magento project which was recently upgraded from Magento 1.x.x to Magento 2.3. I had great trouble installing TaxJar (I have asked a separate question about that here on stackoverflow, when that problem was not solved yet) and now I'm tasked to install all the plugins forgotten to be installed on the original site to the experimental site, which is a Magento 2.3. The list is as follows:

```
Cm_RedisSession 1.8.0.0 (stable)        Redis session
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Default interface for Adminhtml
Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.1.0 (stable)        This is a Magento themes base
Interface_Frontend_Default  1.9.1.0 (stable)        Default interface for Frontend
Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default  1.9.1.0 (stable)        This is a RWD themes base
Interface_Install_Default   1.9.1.0 (stable)        Default interface for Install
Lib_Cm  1.8.0.0 (stable)        Redis adapter for Zend_Cache
Lib_Credis  1.8.0.0 (stable)        Credis Library
Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Google Checkout Library
Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.1 (stable)       Javascript Calendar for Magento
Lib_Js_Ext  1.7.0.0 (stable)        Extjs Javascript Libraries for Magento
Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Javascript Libraries for Magento
Lib_Js_Prototype    1.7.0.0.5 (stable)      Prototype and Scriptaculous Javascript Libraries for Magento
Lib_Js_TinyMCE  3.5.11.0 (stable)       TinyMCE Javascript Libraries for Magento
Lib_LinLibertineFont    2.8.14.1 (stable)       Libertine Open Fonts Project fonts for PDF print-outs
Lib_Mage    1.9.1.0 (stable)        Mage Library
Lib_Magento 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Magento Library
Lib_Phpseclib   1.5.0.0 (stable)        Phpseclib Library
Lib_Varien  1.9.1.0 (stable)        Varien Library
Lib_ZF  1.12.7.0 (stable)       Zend Framework
Lib_ZF_Locale   1.12.7.0 (stable)       Zend Framework Locale
Mage_All_Latest 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Metapackage for latest Magento 1.9.0.0 release
Mage_Centinel   1.9.1.0 (stable)        3D Secure Card Validation
Mage_Compiler   1.9.1.0 (stable)        This module compiles all files of a Magento installation and creates a single include path to increase performance
Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Magento Administration Panel
Mage_Core_Modules   1.9.1.0 (stable)        Collection of Magento Core Modules
Mage_Downloader 1.9.1.0 (stable)        Magento Downloader
Mage_Locale_de_DE   1.9.0.0 (stable)        de_DE locale
Mage_Locale_en_US   1.9.1.0 (stable)        en_US locale
Mage_Locale_es_ES   1.9.0.0 (stable)        es_ES locale
Mage_Locale_fr_FR   1.9.0.0 (stable)        fr_FR locale
Mage_Locale_nl_NL   1.9.0.0 (stable)        nl_NL locale
Mage_Locale_pt_BR   1.9.0.0 (stable)        pt_BR locale
Mage_Locale_zh_CN   1.9.0.0 (stable)        zh_CN locale
Magento_Mobile  1.9.1.0 (stable)        Magento Mobile Xml Interface
Phoenix_Moneybookers    1.3.2.1 (stable)        Moneybookers payment gateway integration
EM_DeleteOrder  1.0.5 (stable)      Enhance Magento feature with ability to delete orders
Bluejalappeno_Orderexport   2.11.1 (stable)         Export your Magento orders in three versatile formats, including exports for CSV, Sage 50 and Highrise
Lib_Pelago  1.9.1.0 (stable)        Pelago Library
```

So far, so good. However, installing plugins to Magento is a mysterious and difficult task for me, because I'm new to Magento and so far my experience is that installing plugins to Magento is time consuming for me. I try for CLI and from UI everything I can, but, with TaxJar, the installation, even though it was attempted many times by my humble self, the last obstacle was removed by someone else, a person who has much more knowledge about Magento. That involved changing table prefixes and updating some records in MySQL.

So, if the items in the list above are all to be installed by me, then I will have to search for all of them one-by-one, download, then upload to the root folder of the project on the server, then unzipping it into a folder (I do not really understand where I need to extract is, what the name of the folder should be, but it seems that it needs to be inside app/code/), but when I tried to do that with Cm_RedisSession, it completely failed.

I tried even with

```
composer require colinmollenhour/magento-redis-session
```

but it didn't affect the list of installed/installable modules and extensions. Now, the example above is a Redis support for Session stuff and thanks to pluginarchive, finding the package is not very difficult. However, doing the upload and extract that many times, besides trying (and failing) to install all the plugins in this list is a very long work to be done, so I wonder whether somehow I could optimise this work, by potentially reducing greatly the number of plugins to install, working only with plugins that are compatible with Magento 2.3.

Of course, I do not intend to install the exact versions the earlier Magento used. For example, in the case of CmRedisSession, we can see at https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/releases that version 1.8.0.0 used by the older Magento installation is a very old version, the newest version, 2.3.3. was released this March. I'm perfectly content with installing version 2.3.3., if it's successful. Unfortunately, it was not successful. Can I somehow reduce the pain of Magento plugin installation by attempting to install only the plugins which are compatible with Magento 2.3?